# Can't acces specific string indices of my json data

Tags: python, json

I'm making a program which gets all the cities of a specific country and how i'm doing that is using a json file which is filled with data and filtering through it with python. However i'm having troubles accesing string indices of my objects and i'm getting a **TypeError** in my traceback.

I've tried converting it to a string and other than that, i'm not really sure what to do.

```py
test = "http://battuta.medunes.net/api/city/fr/search/?region=pa&key=efb0d6bd19fb2f25dc28dccbd7805d59"
resp = requests.get(url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/world-cities/world-cities_json/data/5b3dd46ad10990bca47b04b4739a02ba/world-cities_json.json").json()
data = json.dumps(resp, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
print(data["country"])
```

Example of JSON:

```
    {
        "country": "Zimbabwe",
        "geonameid": 1085510,
        "name": "Epworth",
        "subcountry": "Harare"
    },
    {
        "country": "Zimbabwe",
        "geonameid": 1106542,
        "name": "Chitungwiza",
        "subcountry": "Harare"
    }
```

I expected to be able to get the name of the country. However I just want to be able to accs the values of my data.

Comment: Why do you `json.dumps` your data?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already converting the response in JSON by calling `.json()`, no need to call `json.dumps()`. 
This should work:

```
test = "http://battuta.medunes.net/api/city/fr/search/?region=pa&key=efb0d6bd19fb2f25dc28dccbd7805d59"
resp = requests.get(url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/world-cities/world-cities_json/data/5b3dd46ad10990bca47b04b4739a02ba/world-cities_json.json").json()
print(resp[0]["country"])  # Since resp is a list, so resp[0]["country"] to access first object's country property
```

`json.dumps()` converts `resp` object to `str` which is why you were getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 1):

Your resp is a list of objects, so you should first call the index and then the key:
resp[index][key]

also, line 3 is not required. You have already converted your resp to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `json.dumps`, you can do it like this:

```
test = "http://battuta.medunes.net/api/city/fr/search/?region=pa&key=efb0d6bd19fb2f25dc28dccbd7805d59"
resp = requests.get(url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/world-cities/world-cities_json/data/5b3dd46ad10990bca47b04b4739a02ba/world-cities_json.json").json()

print(resp[0]["country"])
```

But if you still need to use `json.dumps`:

```
test = "http://battuta.medunes.net/api/city/fr/search/?region=pa&key=efb0d6bd19fb2f25dc28dccbd7805d59"
resp = requests.get(url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/world-cities/world-cities_json/data/5b3dd46ad10990bca47b04b4739a02ba/world-cities_json.json").json()
data = json.dumps(resp[0]["country"], sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

print(data)
```